# task.getResult().getDocuments() return [] on android 10 but it's ok on android 8

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I test the app on android 8 and its totally ok but I can't use the app on android 10 and higher
I'm using firebase and each time I try to login on android 10 Login failed
this is my login code
Any Idea where is the problem?
task.getResult().getDocuments() return [] on android 10

```
 private void signIn(){
    loading(true);
    FirebaseFirestore database=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    database.collection(constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USER)
            .whereEqualTo(constants.KEY_EMAIL,binding.inputEmailLogin.getText().toString())
            .whereEqualTo(constants.KEY_PASSWORD,binding.inputPasswordLogin.getText().toString())
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null && task.getResult().getDocuments().size() > 0) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0);
                    preferenceManager.putBooleqn(constants.KEY_IS_SIGN_IN, true);
                    preferenceManager.putString(constants.KEY_USER_ID, documentSnapshot.getId());
                    preferenceManager.putString(constants.KEY_NAME, documentSnapshot.getString(constants.KEY_NAME));
                    preferenceManager.putString(constants.KEY_IMAGE, documentSnapshot.getString(constants.KEY_IMAGE));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    loading(false);
                    showToast("unable to sign in");
                }
            })
    .addOnFailureListener(task -> {

        Log.d("my_er", task.getMessage());

    });

}
```

and this is my logcat Error

```
2022-01-29 14:44:21.338 25527-25570/? E/fbservices:c: Unable to create output stream
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to graph.facebook.com/10.10.34.35 (port 443) from /192.168.1.2 (port 52240) after 10000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1415)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1367)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:219)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:489)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.facebook.rti.common.a.a.c.a(AnalyticsService.java:82)
    at com.facebook.rti.common.a.a.c.a(AnalyticsService.java:60)
    at com.facebook.rti.common.a.a.a.a(AnalyticsHttpClient.java:46)
    at com.facebook.rti.common.a.a.g$b.run(CounterAnalytics.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Does `showToast("unable to sign in");` display something? If `Log.d("my_er", task.getMessage());` displays `[]` then is your onComplete triggered?

Comment: when I run the app the toast ("unable to sign in ") displays and the log message doesn't show anything

Comment: Then most likely you have improper security rules, right?

Comment: I don't know. where can I check that?

Comment: Right in Firebase Console.

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          true
    }
  }
}

Comment: What happens if change `showToast("unable to sign in");` into `showToast(task.getException().getMessage());`, what's the result?

Comment: It crashes without any error message

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: I added, would you mind check it?